# Questions about Mi Sheberach L'olim

Tags: tefilla, torah-service, provenance

It is fairly common *minhag* to recite a blessing for the person receiving an *aliyah* for the Torah reading. The blessing requests that G-d protect the person from misfortune and troubles and make him successful in all his endeavors.

Who and when was this prayer authored? What is "special" about an aliyah that it warrants *any* type of blessing whatsoever, and why this type of blessing (namely protection and success as the main themes)?

Comment: על ג' דברים העולם עומד ועל הכסף הוא זז. As the Olim traditionally donate large sums of money to Shul a motivational blessing was instituted to encourage it. Really!

Comment: I remember the Gemmorah (?) says that it was forbidden to put name plates on things donated to a Shul and people refrained from donating, so they allowed it back.  So people weren't eager to volunteer for Alyot, esp when reading the Torah was required for the Oleh himself, so they offered a sound motivational blessing for every Oleh.

Comment: "It is fairly common minhag to recite a blessing for the person receiving an aliyah for the Torah reading" and for all his relatives up to his third cousins, or that's how it seems sometimes.

Comment: @Heshy Al & I went through a long discussion about your idea, already. *Torach tzibbur*, IMO. And, I feel qualified to say this b/c I've been the Torah reader and as a shul employee, when the shul says "do", you don't argue ;-) But, I wasn't thrilled with it.

Comment: @AlBerko If you can locate the Gemarah or whatever source that forbade name plates, I'd like to see that. If anything, the trend for numerous U.S. shuls (I'd imagine this is worldwide) is to encourage all types of name plates, tags, cutains, stained glass windows, and on and on all over the shul. The only place I can think of that has no names, anywhere is a basement minyan in someone's home, but, even the home minyan is picking up on the name trend.